# Visual Studio with many projects

Tags: c#, asp.net, visual-studio, mef

I am building ASP.NET app with MVC Plugin Framework using Visual Studio 2013. Till now the project has around 20 projects  (main application, custom controls projects, UI helper projects, DAL) however the solution will outgrow to probably 10000s Business Layer projects (each plugin will be in separate project, simple form, unit test and probably db interaction). Those plugins will be auto-discovered using MEF.  I am wondering if this architecture is correct meaning if it will cause performance issues with Visual Studio itself and with whole Asp.net application?

Comment: "10000s Business Layer projects" - wut. Something is seriously wrong with the architecture of your project.

Comment: Well I have 2 options... either have 10000s plugins inside the Main Application Solution or to split them in different projects.

Comment: Not even the most ardent of Photoshop filterwhores in the dregs of deviantArt has that many plugins installed. Please try to think realistically and critically. What are each of these plugins going to perform? On what data?

Comment: Well to give you rough idea, imagine a typical CMS where you have 1000s posts stored in database. In current case instead of having posts I have specific forms which performs tasks. Each plugin will be self contained and will include one or multiple web forms which will do specific tasks, most of them will not be related to each other.

Comment: @Jim why not having just one web form flagged by different type?

Comment: @Jim I cannot really imagine your application would have 1000s of data-entry forms - only a decades-old banking/financial system might have that (and in Cobol too, probably). Try making a list of forms you imagine and you'll run out of imagination sooner rather than later.

Comment: @Jim also, compartmentalizing your application is good, but you don't need to put things in their own VS projects to do this. Just implement good design-patterns in a single project and you'll find it easier to manage.

Comment: @Ivan : can you elaborate bit more? each webform is different, the have they don't have same structure (e.g. one might have 1 input another 20 input textboxes).

Comment: @Dai: the reason of putting plugins in different projects is to use MEF plugin auto-discovery feature. I don't want to build each time whole solution but instead build specific module and throw it in module section where it will be discovered.

Comment: @Jim well, perhaps to make some sort of templates. Every form could have own definition in database. You could then load this definiton only based on type property (for example) and build the form dynamicaly. I'm not sure whether this is possible in your scenario though...just a thought.

Comment: @Dai: Also I am not building a solution which solves one problem (as you mention the banking system). The solution should be open to host as many solving tools as possible.

Comment: @IvanSivak in ideal world I would store view and viewmodel in Database and then restore it when necessary (just as with normal posts)

Comment: @Jim "The solution should be open to host as many solving tools as possible" with a system design like that, I guarantee your project is doomed to failure.

Comment: @Dai: I appreciate your opinion... but this is not the question I am asking here:)